# PHP - Session array cannot see?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i want take people informaiton from my information page.
information page:
$_COOKIE[oda_sayisi] : room number

$

```
i=0;
while ($i < $_COOKIE[oda_sayisi] ) {
                $children=$_COOKIE["child_$i"];
                $adult=$_COOKIE["adult_$i"]+$children;
                $sayi=0;
                while( $adult>= $sayi) {
?>
<input name="name_<?=$i?>[]" type="text"   id="name"  />
<?
$sayi++;
                }


                $i++;

                }
?>
```

And my resulting page code is:

```
function temizle($theValue, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
{
$theValue = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

return $theValue;
}
    foreach ($_POST as $degisken=>$veri ) {
        $_SESSION[$degisken]=temizle($veri);
    }
    echo $_SESSION[name_0][0].'<br> ---';
    echo $_SESSION[name_0][0][0].'<br> ---';
    echo $_SESSION[name_0][0][2].'<br>';
```

When i post the page I get the following result:

```
Array ( [0] => muzaffer ) MUZAFFER 
---M
---Z
```

It's not working $_SESSION[name_0][0] ? Why? someone have anyidea? diffrent way?

Comment: You should start using english variable/function names. You should also quote strings in your PHP code - i.e. `$_SESSION['name_0']` insted of `$_SESSION[name_0]`.

Comment: @TheifMaster Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no requirement to name your variables or functions with English words.

Comment: @chris: sure there isn't. but it's still better - you can never know who'll have to work with your code in the future.

Comment: function temizle($theValue, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
{
$theValue = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

return $theValue;
}

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead

```
<input name="name_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text"   id="name"  />
```

Never use the short  because some server don't have them enabled, I also deleted the [] in the name attribute.

The PHP to make the POST value to `$_SESSION['name_0']`

```
session_start();
$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value ) {
        $_SESSION[$key]= $value;
    }
    print_r( $_POST );
     echo $_SESSION[name_0].'<br> ---';
```

This is working for me.